SFML C++ Why is the text position lower than intended?
Both the point and the text are given a position of 100, 100 But the text in y is below the point
enter image description here
enter image description here
distance varies depending on fonts
default scale and origin
getLocalBounds indicates the correct size
`int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800U, 600U), "Title",sf::Style::Close);
sf::RectangleShape bot(sf::Vector2f(1.0f, 1.0f));

sf::Text text;

sf::Font font;

font.loadFromFile("Data/Textures/Font/Retron2000.ttf");

bot.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
bot.setPosition(100.0f, 100.0f);

text.setFont(font);
text.setString("Hello");
text.setPosition(100.0f, 100.0f);

text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    window.clear(sf::Color::White);

    window.draw(bot);
    window.draw(text);

    window.display();

    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }
}

}`

Can you post the code alongside the problem you are facing?

@Dimitar surely
